# How can I get my app to query an api until data is displayed?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I use the following code to fetch a random date from the API.  The api returns an image URL.  If there is no image URL for this date, I want to keep fetching dates until it returns an image url. Right now the data does not update when calling getRandomPhotos() if no json data is found.

```
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.dev20.themarsroll.models.MarsPhotos
import com.dev20.themarsroll.models.Photo
import com.dev20.themarsroll.repository.MarsPhotoRepository
import com.dev20.themarsroll.util.Resource
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import retrofit2.Response

class MarsPhotoViewModel(

    private val marsPhotoRepository: MarsPhotoRepository
    ): ViewModel() {

    val marsPhotos: MutableLiveData<Resource<MarsPhotos>> = MutableLiveData()

    init {
        getRandomPhotos()
    }

     fun getCuriosityPhotos(solQuery: Int, imgUrlQuery: String, roverQuery: Int, camera: String) = viewModelScope.launch {
        marsPhotos.postValue(Resource.Loading())
        val response = marsPhotoRepository.getCuriosityPhotos(solQuery, imgUrlQuery, roverQuery, camera)
        marsPhotos.postValue(handlePhotosResponse(response))
    }

    private fun handlePhotosResponse(response: Response<MarsPhotos> ) : Resource<MarsPhotos> {
        if(response.isSuccessful) {
            response.body()?.let { resultResponse ->
                if(marsPhotos.value == null) {
                    getRandomPhotos()
                }
                return Resource.Success(resultResponse)
            }
        }
        return Resource.Error(response.message())
    }

    fun getRandomPhotos() {
        getCuriosityPhotos((1..2878).random(), "",5, "NAVCAM")
    }

    fun savePhoto(photo: Photo) = viewModelScope.launch {
        marsPhotoRepository.upsert(photo)
    }

    fun getSavedPhotos() = marsPhotoRepository.getSavedPhotos()

    fun deletePhoto(photo: Photo) = viewModelScope.launch {
        marsPhotoRepository.deletePhoto(photo)
    }
}
```

Photo Data Class

```
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey
import androidx.room.TypeConverters
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName
import java.io.Serializable

@Entity(
    tableName = "photos"
)

@TypeConverters
data class Photo(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int? = null,
    @SerializedName("earth_date")
    val earthDate: String,
    @SerializedName("img_src")
    val imgSrc: String,
    val sol: Int,
    @SerializedName("rover_id")
    val rover: Int,
) : Serializable
```

Comment: I am not sure i understand your question . Well you already know `photo.imgSrc` hols a url or not . So just check for it . Alternatively you can add a placeholder and listener on Glide to check the success or failure

Comment: @ADM I have updated the code and question.  I believe I will need to check for this within my viewmodel, which I have updated above.  I am still not sure where I am going wrong.  When the data is blank, nothing shows up.  I want the method getRandomPhotos() to keep fetching until json data is found

Comment: imgData is not assigned in the code, so it's null all the time and  if (imgData != null) is always false. because of that getRandomPhotos will not called at all... what is the purpose of imgData ? why not checking marsPhotos.value?

Comment: Within my MarsPhotos data class I have a json object "Photo".  Within the Photo data class I have a val called imgSrc that retreives an image URL.   imgData was just trying to check for an image url from the JSON data, but you are right. I did not assign it.  I tried using marsPhotos.value, but the JSON still returns some data no matter what so this will not work either.  I just needs to figure out how to see if this image url is present or not.  I appreciate you taking the time to help.  I think I'm close.

Comment: @ADM for example, I've updated the code to check marsPhotos.value.  The URL queried still returns one data object "photos" as seen here: https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/curiosity/photos?sol=2310&img_url=&rover_id=5&camera=NAVCAM&api_Key=CiloN5MPcn84aMppHASFa43Y1991quOaRA5LmPEw so unfortunately it's never really null & does not work as expected.